# Aurigma file uploader php how to size thumbs with correct ratio

Tags: php, image-resizing, aurigma

I am using aurigma a commercial multi file uploader and cropper.

I am tring to upload images of various aspect ratios and sizes.

I want them to fit into boxes that are 140*140 pixels.

If the height is the smallest attribut of the image I want that to be 140 pixels or vice versa on the width.

Overlap are allowed.

I have looked through the official site and documentation but cannot understand how to do this.

To clarify if an image is 100 * 50 pixels I want it resized to 210 * 140
or an image that is 50*100 should be 140 * 210.

I haven't uploaded any code as the code I have used is available on the main site and I have added nothing specific.

www.aurigma.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use [OrientationalFit](http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu7/P_J_%24au_converter_thumbnailFitMode.htm)?

It works like a Fit mode but with correction on thumbnail orientation.

```
$au.uploader({
    id: 'Uploader1',
    converters: [
        { mode: '*.*=Thumbnail', thumbnailFitMode: 'OrientationalFit',
            thumbnailWidth: 210, thumbnailHeight: 140, 
            thumbnailJpegQuality: 80 }
    ]
});
```

Results:

```
3072 x 2304 => 187 x 140
2304 x 3072 => 140 x 187
```

And one more thing about you sample. Image Uploader cannot be used for upsizing, i.e. thumbnail cannot be larger than source image. This is by design.

Comment: Thats brilliant. Is there a way to set the minimum width of the smallest edge. As what has happened with this code is the largest edge has been resized to 1024 when I need the smallest edge to be 1024 and the largest scaled accordingly.